# Trim (or go up) one level of directory tree in powershell variable

Tags: powershell

Say you have the variable `$source = "C:\temp\one\two\three"` and you want to set `$destination` equal to `$destination = "C:\temp\one\two"` programmatically, how might you do it?

The best idea I've had would be to trim that, but is there a better way?

Perhaps something like

```
$source = "C:\temp\one\two\three"
$dest = "..$source"
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Getting the parent from a DirectoryInfo object, like Lee suggests, will certainly work.
Alternately, if you prefer to use more PowerShellesque commands as opposed to direct .NET Framework calls, you can use PowerShell's built-in Split-Path cmdlet like this:

```
$source      = "C:\temp\one\two\three"

$destination = Split-Path -Path $source -Parent

# $destination will be a string with the value "C:\temp\one\two"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$source = "C:\temp\one\two\three"
$dest = (new-object system.io.directoryinfo $source).parent.fullname
```

EDIT: You can get a `DirectoryInfo` for a directory using `get-item` so you can instead do:

```
$dest = (get-item $source).parent.fullname
```